# 504 Timeout Errors on Google Cloud Run with FastAPI Streaming OpenAI Responses to Flutter App

Tags: flutter, fastapi, google-cloud-run, server-sent-events, openai-api

I deployed a small `FastAPI` project consisting of just three `Python` files to `Google Cloud Run`. This project is designed to stream responses from the `OpenAI` server to my `Flutter` mobile application using `SSE`.

On `Cloud Run`, I have configured the `Request timeout` to 31 seconds.

On the mobile app side, I have set the `timeout` to 10 seconds. If the client does not receive any data from the stream within this time, I regard it as a failed request.

However, something strange is happening with my server. Sometimes, all requests receive a timeout error with code 504, and this lasts for about 5 minutes. After the series of `504 error logs`, there is a list of Traceback logs.

I suspect that something is blocking the thread, resulting in all requests being queued, but I can't identify the issue. Could you please review the code and provide some insight?

```py
#main.py:
from dependencies import denpendency
from routers import chat_v1
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status, Depends
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse

app = FastAPI(
    title='FastAPI API',
    openapi_url='/',
    docs_url='/docs',
    dependencies=[Depends(denpendency.validate_jwt)],
)
app.include_router(chat_v1.router)


@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    return PlainTextResponse(str(exc.detail), status_code=exc.status_code)


@app.exception_handler(RuntimeError)
async def runtime_exception_handler(request, exc):
    return PlainTextResponse(str(exc.detail), status_code=exc.status_code)


@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def exception_handler(request, exc):
    return PlainTextResponse(str(exc))


@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    exc_str = f'{exc}'.replace('\n', ' ').replace('   ', ' ')
    logging.error(f"{request}: {exc_str}")
    content = {'status_code': 10422, 'message': exc_str, 'data': None}
    return JSONResponse(content=content, status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
```

```py
#denpendency.py:
from fastapi import Header, HTTPException, Depends
from fastapi.security import HTTPAuthorizationCredentials, HTTPBearer
from firebase_admin import auth, credentials, initialize_app

cred = credentials.Certificate("assets/credentials/sa.json")
default_app = initialize_app(cred)
print("Name: " + default_app.name)


def validate_jwt(credential: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(HTTPBearer(auto_error=False))):
    if cred is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401,
            detail="Bearer authentication is needed",
            headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer realm="auth_required"'},
        )
    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(credential.credentials)
    except Exception as err:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401,
            detail=f"Invalid authentication from Firebase. {err}",
            headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer error="invalid_token"'},
        )
    return decoded_token
```

```py
#chat_v1.py:

async def get_answer_stream(request: Request, body: ChatRequest):
    try:
        message_stream = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k',
            messages=get_messages(body),
            stream=True,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = "OpenAI Response (Streaming) Error: " + str(e)
        print(error_message)
        return

    try:
        for chunk in message_stream:
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                print("Disconnected!")
                break
            choices = chunk["choices"][0]
            delta = choices["delta"]
            if 'content' in delta:
                content = chunk["choices"][0]["delta"]['content']
                done = False
            else:
                content = None
                done = 'finish_reason' in choices and choices['finish_reason'] == 'stop'
            yield json.dumps({"token": content, "done": done})
    except CancelledError:
        print("User stop generating message")
    except Exception as e:
        print("OpenAI Response (Streaming) Error: " + str(e))
    finally:
        print('Finish Stream flow')
        await request.close()


@router.post(
    "/getAnswer",
    tags=["chat-v1"],
    response_model=str,
    responses={503: {"detail": error503}}
)
async def get_answer_v1(request: Request):
    body = await request.json()
    chat_request = ChatRequest(
        messages=body.get('messages'),
        tag=body.get('tag'),
        prompts=body.get('prompts'),
    )
    answer = get_answer_stream(request, chat_request)
    # from sse_starlette.sse import EventSourceResponse
    result = EventSourceResponse(answer)
    return result
```

```
{
//504 error message
httpRequest: {10}
insertId: "64ac6a5c000aabf6c037a3b0"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/projectname/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-07-10T20:30:20.846742621Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
spanId: "9149462740768920648"
textPayload: "The request has been terminated because it has reached the maximum request timeout. To change this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout"
timestamp: "2023-07-10T20:29:49.696909Z"
trace: "projects/projectname/traces/49407a47b7bb6d0953078dbf9416aa1b"
}
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 373, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 226, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function( 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 159, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values) 
  File "/app/./routers/chat_v1.py", line 106, in get_answer_v1
    body = await request.json() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/requests.py", line 227, in json
    body = await self.body() 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/requests.py", line 220, in body
    async for chunk in self.stream(): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/requests.py", line 214, in stream
    raise ClientDisconnect()
```

[image: Error logs image]

Comment: You are logging HTTP 504 Gateway Timeout at 31 seconds. Why did you select 31 seconds for the timeout? Why are you not implementing [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff)? If the Cloud Run timeout is 31 seconds why is the client timeout 10 seconds? My guess is that OpenAI is rate-limiting your service and your code incorrectly manages that condition.